# Align includes other than align assignment

Tags: visual-studio, editor, indentation, productivity-power-tools

*Visual Studio Productivity Tools* provide the ability to align assignments to the same level.

Example:

From:

```
import import1 = require('import1');
import someLongerImport = require('someLongerImport');
import import2 = require('./some/folder/import');
```

To:

```
import import1          = require('import1');
import someLongerImport = require('someLongerImport');
import import2          = require('./some/folder/import');
```

---

What I need now is the ability to align other things than assignments that could be specified by some regex.

Example:

From:

```
import import1 = require('import1');
import {differentSyntax} from 'someLongerImport';
import * as evenMoreSyntax from './some/folder/import';
```

To:

```
import import1              = require('import1');
import {differentSyntax}    from 'someLongerImport';
import * as evenMoreSyntax  from './some/folder/import';
```

---

Does *Visual Studio Productivity Tools* provide such functionality or are there any other plug-ins that could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is the [Code alignment](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd) extension that supports exactly that.

I have now created a `=\ *require\('.*?'\);?|from \'.*?';?` regex pattern alignment which works perfectly fine.